# RSS Feed Search Engine

Tags: api, rss, rss-reader

I'm looking for a query based RSS Feed search engine sort of like a modern day based web search engine like Google, bing, yahoo og baudi.

Does anybody know any good RSS feed query based search engines. I'm looking along the lines of public API's of course.

Answer (score 1):

A simple Google search comes up with a bunch of different (free) RSS feed search APIs:

Farco offers web/news/feed search - http://www.faroo.com/hp/api/api.html

Feedly also offers great RSS feed search - https://developer.feedly.com/v3/search/